# PHP document_root

Tags: php, mysql, html

I am trying to access the PHP custom page which is inside a folder but I'm having two major problems!

1. PHP document root not working

   ```
   <?php echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'folder_name/files_name.php';?>
   ```
2. Destination path is directing from parent file.

   ```
   home3/parent-folder/public_html/folder001/folder002/folder_name/file_name.php
   ```

Website: http://design.logohour.com/

Page File: http://design.logohour.com/home3/advertania/public_html/Logohour/logopexcil/services/custom-logo-design.php

Error is 404 Page not Found!

Comment: Looks like that page is actually accessed from http://design.logohour.com/services/custom-logo-design.php. I think you are mixing up the server path and website path.

Comment: that is correct ,, the right address is the same as you mentioned

Comment: So is your problem solved?

Comment: no I am strugging

Comment: Sorry I can't see your problem. What are you trying to do?

Comment: as I have mentioned as well as you found that I am mixing up the server part. Actually I am new to php and trying to understand but cant figure out the problem ...  I need to target a page through php which is inside the new folder and the document root is not working I have mentioned the actual codes in my question

Comment: What do you mean when you say "target"? Do you mean you are trying to `include()` it? Or using it in a link like `<a href=""></a>`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190163/discussion-between-syed-muhammad-iftikhar-and-kodos-johnson).

Comment: Sorry I was away from my computer. You should just do: `href="/services/custom-logo-design.php"`

Comment: Ok great its resolved ... I must appreciate... but now the new challenege is ((Warning: include(includes/header.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home3/.....)) .... Also Just need an advise .. can I hide any of the folder from the path ...  for example href="/services/custom-logo-design.php" This hireharchy if I want to hide services folder on the front side ??